# globally duplicate IDs for nsid

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel

I am on Arch Linux and I use two identical solid-state drives (ADATA Swordfish 1 TB M.2 NVMe SSD). Since May maybe June, I cannot boot into my system after an update (because of my setup I need both SSDs to boot).
Journalctl lists an error:

> nvme nvme0: globally duplicate IDs for nsid 1

`lsblk` lists only one SSD. Is there a way I can use my two SSDs with a recent version of Arch Linux?

**Edit1:**
When I use the arch iso "archlinux-2022.05.01-x86_64" as live usb I do not get the error message "nvme nvme0: globally duplicate IDs for nsid 1" and everything works as expected.
When I use "archlinux-2022.06.01-x86_64" I get the error message.

**Edit2:**
Logs using "archlinux-2022.06.01-x86_64" iso:

**parted -l**

```
Model: ELECOM MF-PKU3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 31.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  20.3GB  20.3GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
 2      20.3GB  31.0GB  10.7GB  primary  ext3


Model: ADATA SWORDFISH (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   ext4         boot
 2      538MB   1000GB  1000GB               root
```

**lsblk -a**

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0 688.2M  1 loop  
sda           8:0    1  28.9G  0 disk  
|-sda1        8:1    1  18.9G  0 part  
`-sda2        8:2    1    10G  0 part  /usb_data
nvme1n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
|-nvme1n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part  
`-nvme1n1p2 259:2    0   931G  0 part  
  `-myData  254:0    0   931G  0 crypt /
```

**ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/**

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 13:24 dm-name-myData -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 13:24 dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-6dc7a196d80a42c392ca7cb680087d9b-myData -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 30 13:27 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K38291A16EC -> ../../nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 13:27 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K38291A16EC-part1 -> ../../nvme1n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 13:27 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K38291A16EC-part2 -> ../../nvme1n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 30 13:27 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084 -> ../../nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 13:27 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part1 -> ../../nvme1n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 13:27 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part2 -> ../../nvme1n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 30 13:27 usb-ELECOM_MF-PKU3_070825BA33A08E37-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 13:27 usb-ELECOM_MF-PKU3_070825BA33A08E37-0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 13:27 usb-ELECOM_MF-PKU3_070825BA33A08E37-0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
```

**Edit3:**
Logs using "archlinux-2022.05.01-x86_64" iso:

**parted -l**

```
Model: ELECOM MF-PKU3 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 31.0GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  20.3GB  20.3GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
 2      20.3GB  31.0GB  10.7GB  primary  ext3


Model: ADATA SWORDFISH (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 2      106MB   123MB   16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 3      123MB   1000GB  1000GB               Basic data partition          msftdata
 4      1000GB  1000GB  540MB   ntfs                                       hidden, diag


Model: ADATA SWORDFISH (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   ext4         boot
 2      538MB   1000GB  1000GB               root
```

**lsblk -a**

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
loop0         7:0    0 669.2M  1 loop  
sda           8:0    1  28.9G  0 disk  
|-sda1        8:1    1  18.9G  0 part  
`-sda2        8:2    1    10G  0 part  /usb_data
nvme1n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
|-nvme1n1p1 259:8    0   512M  0 part  
`-nvme1n1p2 259:9    0   931G  0 part  
  `-myData  254:0    0   931G  0 crypt /
nvme0n1     259:3    0 931.5G  0 disk  
|-nvme0n1p1 259:4    0   100M  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p2 259:5    0    16M  0 part  
|-nvme0n1p3 259:6    0 930.9G  0 part  
`-nvme0n1p4 259:7    0   515M  0 part
```

**ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/**

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 15:03 dm-name-myData -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 15:03 dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS2-6dc7a196d80a42c392ca7cb680087d9b-myData -> ../../dm-0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K38291A16EC -> ../../nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K38291A16EC-part1 -> ../../nvme1n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K38291A16EC-part2 -> ../../nvme1n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K382LAAQAWP -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K382LAAQAWP-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K382LAAQAWP-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K382LAAQAWP-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-ADATA_SWORDFISH_2K382LAAQAWP-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084 -> ../../nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part1 -> ../../nvme1n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part2 -> ../../nvme1n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Jul 30 15:04 usb-ELECOM_MF-PKU3_070825BA33A08E37-0:0 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 15:04 usb-ELECOM_MF-PKU3_070825BA33A08E37-0:0-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 30 15:04 usb-ELECOM_MF-PKU3_070825BA33A08E37-0:0-part2 -> ../../sda2
```

**Edit4:**

**lspci -nn -d ::0108**

```
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5763] (rev 01)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5763] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of (as root) `parted -l`, `lsblk -a`, `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/`, that could help.

Answer (score 2):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084 -> ../../nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part1 -> ../../nvme1n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part2 -> ../../nvme1n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jul 30 15:04 nvme-eui.00000000010000004ce00018dd8c9084-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
```

This would seem to suggest that both your NVMe drives have the same EUI value on their first (and probably only) namespace. The `/dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.*` links of `nvme0n1` have been overwritten by the corresponding links of `nvme1n1`, so that only the links for partitions `nvme0n1p3` and `nvme0n1p4` are left over since `nvme1n1` does not have those partitions.

[Apparently at least some other ADATA NVMe models have the same issue.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/nvme/host?h=v5.19-rc8&id=1629de0e0373e04d68e88e6d9d3071fbf70b7ea8)

> nvme-pci: add NVME_QUIRK_BOGUS_NID for ADATA XPG SX6000LNP (AKA SPECTRIX S40G)
>
> ADATA XPG SPECTRIX S40G drives report bogus eui64 values that appear to
> be the same across drives in one system. Quirk them out so they are
> not marked as "non globally unique" duplicates.

If you can build your own custom kernel, it would be easy to add a quirk entry similar to the patch linked above: you would just need to use `lspci -nn` to figure out the PCI vendor:product IDs of your ADATA Swordfish NVMes, and then add an entry like this to the quirk list at `<kernel source>/drivers/nvme/host/pci.c`:

```
{ PCI_DEVICE(0x<vendor ID>, 0x<product ID>),   /* ADATA Swordfish 1 TB */
    .driver_data = NVME_QUIRK_BOGUS_NID, },
```

The [check for duplicate IDs was added to the upstream kernels in 2022-02-28](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/nvme/host/core.c?h=v5.19-rc8&id=2079f41ec6ffaad9aa51ca550105b2228467aec7), modified to [allow non-unique private namespaces in 2022-03-29](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/nvme/host/core.c?h=v5.19-rc8&id=5974ea7ce0f9a5987fc8cf5e08ad6e3e70bb542e) and had the [NVME_QUIRK_BOGUS_NID quirk mechanism added in 2022-04-15](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/nvme/host/core.c?h=v5.19-rc8&id=00ff400e6deee00f7b15e200205b2708b63b8cf6).

Comment: The result of lspci -nn does not contain ADATA or Swordfish

Comment: Okay, please run `lspci -nn -d ::0108`  and add the output into your original question. ADATA seems to have been using multiple vendor IDs, so `lspci` might not be able to correctly identify all of them. But that command should list any NVMe devices your system has.